# How to de-serialize JSON array of array of strings in C#

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

I have the following JSON format.

```
{
    "INIT": ["string", "string"],
    "QUIT": ["string", "string", "string"],
    "SYN": [
        ["string", "string", "string", "string"],
        ["string", "string", "string", "string", "string"],
        ["string", "string", "string"]
    ]
}
```

I am using the following C# class template,

```
[DataContract]
public class TemplateClass
{
    [DataMember(Name = "INIT")]
    public string[] init;

    [DataMember(Name = "QUIT")]
    public string[] quit;

    [DataMember(Name = "SYN")]
    public Synonym[] synonyms;
}


[DataContract]
public class Synonym
{
    [DataMember]
    public string[] words;
}
```

When I run the following code, it doesn't de-serialize the strings in 'SYN'. Please refer to the image below.

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(jsonFilePath))
   {
      DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(TemplateClass));
      dataObject = (TemplateClass) jsonSerializer.ReadObject(reader.BaseStream);
   }
```

[image]

Comment: Use an automated code-generation tool like http://json2csharp.com/, you will see `SYN` should be `public List<List<string>> SYN { get; set; }` or `public string [][] SYN { get; set; }`

Comment: Your JSON and class is not in sync. As per four class the JSON should be like this:  `"SYN": [{"words::[]},{"words":},..]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON has SYN as an array of an array of strings where you are defining it in c# as an array of objects of type 'Synonym' but not specifying a property. You could define synonyms as a string[][] or change your JSON to include the property name words so:

```
{
    "INIT": ["string", "string"],
    "QUIT": ["string", "string", "string"],
    "SYN": [
       {"words": ["string", "string", "string", "string"]},
        {"words":["string", "string", "string", "string", "string"]},
       {"words":["string", "string", "string"]}
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Newtonsoft` library and the following method

```
String[] strArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(jsonArray);
```

Comment: I can't use any third-party lib.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
    string json = "{\"INIT\": [\"string\", \"string\"], \"QUIT\": [\"string\", \"string\", \"string\"], \"SYN\": [ [\"string\", \"string\", \"string\", \"string\"],[\"string\", \"string\", \"string\", \"string\", \"string\"],[\"string\", \"string\", \"string\"]]}";
    Dictionary<string, object> convert = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```